# C# Powershell Script Not Writing to Output in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a simple WPF Form where I want the output of a certain powershell script to be written to the Visual Studio Output. However, I'm not getting the right output in Visual Studio.

Powershell:

```
nmap -O 198.168.1.1/24
```

I have a wpf form with just a button for now, here's the code:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I am Here!");
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddScript(@"C:\Research\Network Scanner\powerscript.ps1");

        Collection<PSObject> resultsN = null;

        resultsN = ps.Invoke();

        Debug.WriteLine(resultsN);

        // ps.Invoke();
    }
}
```

}

Output:

I am Here!

The thread 0x4378 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]

Answer (score 0):

This will help.
foreach(PSObject obj in results)
{
Debug.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
}